# Where to find the puranas with slokas in it

Tags: puranas

I wanted to know if there is any site/book to read the puranas with slokas in it.

Comment: Try https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana. E.g., Here's the link to the first chapter from Kurma Purana: https://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30550/79_chapter_1_1.pdf